# How to show only one entree per author from a found list of authors

Tags: channel-entries, stash, filter, author

Situation: A channel tag gets feeded by an array of author ID's, thus outputting all entrees of the selected authors.

Problem: I must restrict these entrees to one per author.

Solution: Should we use a PHP script to hide or delete entrees?
Or are there other methodes we could use?

I found a simulair question here [How to show recent entries restricted to one per author?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25074/how-to-show-recent-entries-restricted-to-one-per-author) but I do not know how to implement it.

My code is like this -where {exp:stash:AllLetterAuthor} produces a pipeline separated array of author_id-:

```
    {exp:stash:parse
process="end"
scope="local"
replace="yes"
save="no"
refresh="1"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
                                    channel="my_channel-1|my_channel-2"
                                    disable="pagination|category-fields|member-data"
                                    dynamic="no"
                                    author_id="{exp:stash:AllLetterAuthor}"
                                    parse="inward"
                                    }
                                    {my_field}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

The above code works, I get all the publications of the authors, but I want only one per author.

I hope someone can help me here, thank you very much!